# How is a object with local variables stored in the heap?

Tags: c++, object, dynamic, heap-memory, local

Suppose I have a class that has local variables, like this one:

```
class Object{
 private:
 int number1, number2, number3;


 public:
 Object(){
 number1=0;
 number2=0;
 number3=0;
 }

}
```

Now let's suppose I use it in my main program:

```
int main (){
Object obj1();
}
```

I created my object locally in main. Since I did not use "new" it does not use the heap. All the object's variables (and the object itself) are stored in the stack.

Now suppose I used new in main, like this:

```
int main (){
Object p= new obj1();
}
```

Now I only have one variable in my main: a pointer that points to obj1 in the heap.

My class notes say this is possible and correct: that you can dynamically create an object that has local variables. But how exactly is the compiler able to create the object in the heap? My object's variables number1, number2 and number3 do not use new. They are local variables and local variables need a local scope. I get that the object "p" is on the heap because we used "new". But what about its members? They don't use new. Is there some kind of automatic cast so that these local variables are made dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

Once you call things their proper C++ names, the question becomes very easy to understand.

> Suppose I have a class that has local variables, like this one:

Classes do not have *local* variables; only functions and constructors do. Your class has *member* variables.

> My class notes say this is possible and correct: that you can dynamically create an object that has local variables. But how exactly is the compiler able to create the object in the heap?

Unlike local variables, which are placed in the automatic storage (often nicknamed "the stack") member variables go wherever the object goes. If the object is in the automatic storage, its member variables are in the automatic storage as well. If the object is in dynamic storage area (often nicknamed "the heap") then its member variables are in the heap, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for being so dumb.

Answer (score 1):

A class doesn't have local variables, it has *member* variables.

And the size of an object includes the member variables. If you print `sizeof(Object)` you will see it change as you add or remove member variables.

So the `new` invocation will allocate space for the full object including its member variables (as reported by `sizeof(Object)`), and the *construction of those variables will happen as part of the `Object` construction call.

Comment: Thank you. Everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic Object Oriented concept. Declaring a class with member does not allocate any memory unless you create an object of that class (also called instantiating the class). An exception to this is when you declare your say "number1" as static. In that case, it will belong to the class and every object will get the same memory holding value of "number1". In that case, it will be called "class variable" rather than "member variable". Hope this helps!